# How to get an answer's web address?

Tags: discussion

When refer/link to other people's answer, it is quite convenient to jump directly to that answer. How to get that specific answer's web address?

Comment: Do you mean *other than the obvious share link* on every question and answer?

Comment: @KenWhite I didn't aware there's a share link, my bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

click the share button underneath the answer

Comment: Share buttons seem to return strange links, though...