# Question Share Button Provides Needlessly Long Link

Tags: support, sharing

Links generated by the share button [like this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/309621/3398839) are needlessly long. Here's an example:

`https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/309621/3398839` should be `https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/309621`.

It seems that the URLs are in the form of:

```
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/<entire question ID>/<specific question/answer ID>#comment<comment ID>_<specific question/answer ID>
```

And shorten to:

```
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/<entire question ID>/<modified question title>/<specific question/answer ID>#comment<comment ID>_<specific question/answer ID>
```

Here are more examples:

- `https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/309621/309622`
- `https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/309621/309622#comment267812_309621`
- `https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/309622/3398839`
- `https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/309621/309622#comment334812_309622`

The third example is particularly strange because it seems to use `/a` instead of `/q`, presumably because it is an answer and not a question. What is even more interesting is that it seems to have the same answer ID as the previous example, but the second number is equal to the second number of the original URL.

What is that second number, and why is it here? What is the point?

(sorry for the drama)

Comment: If you prefer shorter links without userId (I do), [this userscript](http://stackapps.com/q/6507) can help.

Answer (score 6):

The second ID number is *your user ID*. It has nothing to do with any post, and will not redirect you to an answer. I don't know how you got an answer ID on the end of it, but it didn't come out of the share box that way - you're essentially attributing the link to whoever has the user ID 309622, which goes to a deleted user.

That ID number is used to track progress for the [Publicist class badge set](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/262/publicist) which is awarded for getting so many unique views through your "referral" link.

The `/q` path is used for questions and the `/a` path is used for answers. However, both go to the same parser and it will look at whatever the post ID is in order to determine the redirect it needs to use to get you to that post (so you can mix the q and a around and it will make no difference whatsoever).

Comment: What do you mean by "the second ID"? If you mean what I labeled as the specific question/answer ID, the reason I guessed that was because multiple answers to the same question have different 2nd IDs but equal 1st IDs.